# ScrollView not working inside CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-scrollview

I have already searched SO and none of the answer helped me.

Here is my layout xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/layout_building"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/scrollview_nested_fragment_container"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/views_container">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_building_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        </ScrollView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I'm adding child views to my `LinearLayout` dynamically via code. I have also tried to move the `ScrollView` tag to wrap `CardView` but still no luck. Is this a limitation of `CardView` or do any one know a working solution to this.

Comment: add android:fillViewport="true" in ScrollView.

Comment: You need to set height of cardview accordingly. Make it match parent or fixed size.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya setting static height did make the scrollview work

Comment: @SangeetSuresh can't make cardview match_parent as i want it to grow according to number of child views.

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya not working

Comment: Try to add CardView inside scroll view and then check.

Comment: @Furqan already tried, no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay first of all thanks to every one for helping with your valauble suggestions. The actual problems lies with the `ConstraintLayout`. All needs to be done is add a constraint `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to the cardview and set `android:layout_height="0dp"`. The cardview didn't have any boundary inforced. Unlike LinearLayout and RelativeLayout which by default inforce the boundary to their child views.

Answer (score 4):

It will be better if you use [**`NestedScrollView`** .](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as
>   both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        //Your CHILD Layout

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**FYI**

You can put your **`CardView`** under **`ScrollView`**.

Comment: Same behavior no scroll.

Comment: i believe nested scrollview is meant to be for a scrolling container inside another scroll able container.

Comment: Cardview is just a static viewgroup

Comment: @eCDroid My suggestion, Put your CARDVIEW inside SCROLLVIEW.

Comment: Please read the question. I have tried this before asking question.

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion. `FYI: You can put your CardView under ScrollView.` You deserved the upvote.

Comment: But the actual solution was to add app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" to my cardview. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

set this property in ScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

and set height of cardview to match parent or fixed

Comment: okay, I just seen you set CardView width to 0dp. please also fixed or match parent it

Comment: it has weight on it.